# How to props through the deeply nested child to parent data ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To explain the situation. I have a child component that has one chevron that spins on a click. I need to implement from child to parent and to grand parent props data.

```
<ChildComponent>
<ParentComponent>
<GrandParentComponent>
```

Inside **ChildComponent** I have arrow icon ( img )

```
  const [rotateIcon, setRotateIcon] = useState(false);

  const expandAttachment = useCallback(() => {
    setRotateIcon(!rotateIcon); 
  }, [rotateIcon]);


  <img src="assets/arrow" transform={rotateIcon ? 'rotate(90deg)' : 'rotate(0)'} >
```

And this is work but.... I need to props **rotateIcon** state to **GrandParentComponent** compoentent.

It’s not just the child to the parent. Than child to parent and from parent another level up to. GrandParent.

How do I do that? Is this a good way at all? What are my alternatives? I do not use **redux** in the system, but api context!

To be clear. All three components are connected.
Each to each is a child parent!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have 3 options:

1. Store the state props in the parent of all components, which is too complex for this purpose I think.
2. Use Redux to handle state management for the app
3. Use Context API to handle the state management for the app as a global state.
   You can check out this blog for this:
   [https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/react-context-api/#:~:text=What%20is%20Context%20API%3F,to%20parent%2C%20and%20so%20on](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/react-context-api/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Context%20API%3F,to%20parent%2C%20and%20so%20on).

I do however use and recommend using redux for complex operations like this. When you understand the idea behind redux it becomes very easy to use it.

Comment: i know redux state menagement but application is small and there is no need for redux....

Answer (score 0):

store the state in the `GrandParentComponent` and pass through in between components as a prop to reach `ChildComponent`.
Props are meant to be passed from a *parent component* to a *child component(s)*.

Comment: Hmmm.. because i post question..i not sure how to do it...
First what to use ( except REDUX )
Api context ( Which is already include in project )  or pass through components.. And when know what to use, i am not sure how

Answer (score 0):

You can do [prop drilling](https://medium.com/swlh/avoid-prop-drilling-with-react-context-a00392ee3d8) i.e, adding a state to `<GrandParentComponent/>` component and passing it as prop to the child components.

**grandparent**

```
export default GrandParentComponent(){
    const [rotateIcon, setRotateIcon] = useState(false);

    // pass the state and setState down to the children
    return <ParentComponent rotateIcon={rotateIcon} setRotateIcon={setRotateIcon}/> 
}
```

**parent**

```
export default ParentComponent({rotateIcon, setRotateIcon}){
    // pass props to child component again
    return <ChildComponent rotateIcon={rotateIcon} setRotateIcon={setRotateIcon}/> 
}
```

**child**

```
export default ChildComponent({rotateIcon, setRotateIcon}){
  const expandAttachment = useCallback(() => {
    setRotateIcon(!rotateIcon); 
  }, [rotateIcon]);

  <img src="assets/arrow" transform={rotateIcon ? 'rotate(90deg)' : 'rotate(0)'} >
}
```

There’s nothing inherently bad about prop drilling, but it gets harder to manage the state of the app as the complexity increases.

To avoid this we either use React Context or Redux. React Context is baked into react itself, so it's very lightweight and powerful at the same time. It is the perfect fit for a situation like yours.

To keep the answer short, read on how to implement React Context and useContext hook [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/).

Comment: Yes i will use context api